# Trying to get my listView to start an activity. Getting a weird error

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a listView in a fragment and I'm trying to use a switch statement to direct everyone to the rightful activity. Just can't get it to work. I've been messing around with the code for about an hour, but I'm still getting the same error when creating an intent.

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {
    String[] menu = { "Setting", "About" };

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu));

        getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(newActivity1);
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Here are my errors:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving the Intent's constructor a Fragment instance as the first parameter, where the current Activity should go.

Try this:

```
Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getActivity(), About.class);
```

Comment: What's the difference between getActivity() and getApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 2):

try as:

```
switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Settings.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
            startActivity(newActivity1);
            break;

        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between getActivity() and getApplicationContext()?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29  both are totally different

Comment: Thanks Zsombor's code worked for me, but I will read the documentation and try your method.

Comment: @EGHDK : both code work but difference is that in my code i'm passing current application context as first parameter

Comment: So is one method better than another?

Comment: i think, getApplicationContext() is better  because it return  latest context for starting an new Activity.